# Spring MVC How to sort BindingResult form with hibernate validator errors

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

I have a huge problem with BindingResult errors order. let's say we have:

```
public class MyForm {

    @NotEmpty(message = "Not empty")
    private String name;
    @Email(message = "Not valid email")
    private String email;
    }
```

And my controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/my-url", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String execute(@Valid @ModelAttribute("form") MyForm form, BindingResult result, Model model) {
            if(result.hasErrors()) {
    //I need to sort the list here
                return "/my-url";
            }

    //rest of the code
    }
```

BindingResult extends AbstractBindingResult,and you can get errors list, but it's implementation looks like this (AbstractBindingResult.class):

```
private final List<ObjectError> errors = new LinkedList<ObjectError>();

    @Override
    public List<ObjectError> getAllErrors() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(this.errors);
    }
```

Finally I'm unable to sort this list, change it or do anything else. I tried reflection, but it's not a good solution. Is there any other way to keep errors in same order as fields in MyForm ?

Comment: Why would you need even to do that? You should be using the form tags to display the errors, wy are you trying to work around that? If you really want, just create a new list based on the other one and sort that. It is unmodifiable for a reason and that should be trigger you are doing something you shouldn't be doing in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. It's not possible to put new sorted list instead of current, because it's final. If there's any other way to keep errors in same order as fields on the form It would be great. Sorting list was just one of my ideas.

Comment: As stated you shouldn't be doing that, if you need that, you are doing things wrong (also imho that is). You shouldn't be using the `getAllErrors` method you should use the proper tags (or integration for your web framework of choice) to display the errors.

Comment: Thanks. I see it's wrong direction. It's not my code. I will find other solution.